# Congrats to Benedikt Bauer on reviewing 500 first posts!

Tags: discussion

That's a lot of first posts.

Jimirings passed that a long time ago ...

Well done [Benedikt](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/5271/benedikt-bauer)!

Comment: Where do you see that? Is it a badge or is there some secret stats page I'm missing?

Comment: @Mσᶎ  Its available in the mouse-over on the [Review](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/review) page and also on this [Stats](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats) page.

Comment: Daaaaaaaaaamn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the congrats, Andy.

As I do not have that much time to take part more actively at the moment, I try to do at least some maintenance tasks to help the community. It's nice to see that some people see and reward that.

Comment: Gratulation Benedikt! :)